# How to understand website is sending uploaded files to its server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, websocket

How can I understand uploaded files are permanently stored in the website's server?
For example, how can I understand when I uploaded my PDF file to this website (https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-jpg) whether its also saves my file to its server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a third party server that you have no control over there is no programmatic way of determining if they are in fact storing your pdfs permanently.

They might have a Terms and Conditions page where they set out the terms and conditions of using their service.

Alternatively if it concerns you try to find a site that makes it clear that they do not store your files permanently.